# Wait for JavaScript function to finish before proceed

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, callback

This might not be a complicated question but I'm not sure if I'm on the right track here.

My goal is to run a JavaScript function first and when the execution is completely finished (this may take up to a few seconds, but not always) close the window.

The function and closing is triggered by just 1 button:

```
<button id="myID">Click me</button>
```

The JavaScript is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function someFunction() {
        // do some stuff
    }

    document.getElementById('myID').addEventListener("click", function(){
        someFunction();
        window.close();
    });
</script>
```

This works fine, but can get anyone give some advice if this is a reliable method or not? It is important that execution of the function is fully completed before **window.close()** is triggered.

Comment: I presume you're not _actually_ doing an `alert` in that function? But rather some kind of [async] I/O (ajax request or whatnot)?

Comment: Unless `someFunction` has code expecting asynchronous results, such as an ajax request, and you want those completed before closing the window, then yes, the rest of the code is guaranteed to execute after it.

Comment: OP if you explain what the function actually does it will a) save everyone guessing and b) you'll get a better answer.

Comment: @Andy someFunction() does some DOM manipulation after a page has loaded. The execution time really depends on the browser, cpu speed etc. There is no AJAX involved here.

Comment: @elton73 In that case, you need to ask yourself, if you are doing anything asynchronous, or not. DOM manipulation is synchronous.

Comment: @vicbyte Synchronous it is then. My code should be fine here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can put your `window.close()` right under your `alert();`. However, if you would like to add more asynch stuff, you want a callback function like this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var closeWindow = function() {
        window.close();
    };

    function someFunction(callback) {
        alert('hi');
        callback();
    }

    document.getElementById('myID').addEventListener("click", function(){
        someFunction(closeWindow);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Why would he need a callback if he does synchronous stuff only?

Comment: Is it not safer to use a callback function in case he wants to add asynch stuffs?

Comment: No, the OP does not need a callback here.

Comment: As a note: instead of `var closeWindow = function() {}` you should write `function closeWindow() {}` there is no need or benefit of using an assignment expression here. Using an expression indicates that the `closeWindow` variable might have a different function assigned at later point or different place.

Comment: True, however, I almost put ()=>{} as well as I like to make them learn similitude in coding.

Comment: Using the arrow function just because it’s new and shorter to write instead of its features is also not good. A `var closeWindow = () => {}` is not better. One could argue about the benefits of `const closeWindow =`. I personally don’t like it, but it see it’s benefits, but a `var` or `let` assignment for something that does not change is something you should not do.

Answer (score 2):

Synchronous javascript will always be run in the top-down order and will always guarantee that instruction one will be finished before instruction two.

But, there is also an asynchronous part (you don't have it here, but for example ajax requests are often asynchronous), that is executed differently and requires [callbacks](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Callback_function)/[promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).

Answer (score 0):

Your options are:

1. put `window.close();` in the callback function
2. use promises this way you can control if the callback execution /if there is an error you can handle it better and not close the window/

Answer (score 0):

> someFunction() does some DOM manipulation after a page has loaded

Thats synchronous (the browser might defer the rendering, but were talking about milliseconds here), and therefore it is guaranteed that the DOM manipulation is done before the function returns.